# UISearchBar animation issue

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UIViewController in which I want to show a tableview with the serchBar.

```
//viewDidLoad
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                           0, 
                                                           SCREEN_WIDTH(),
                                                           SCREEN_HEIGHT())
                                                    style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:_tableView];

// adding uisearch bar
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

_tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

//
 searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
```

The issue happens when I click inside the uisearch bar so that the animation starts and it looks like it has a 20px unwanted offset.

Comment: can you add me to NSChat group. Also experiment these dimensions in a IB and see if problem still persists. And what dimensions will remove this problem can also be inferred from IB

Comment: Are you using any kind of animations ? @luca

Comment: No.. Just added the UIsearchbar to the tableview header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reminder for anyone with similar issues. I needed to add this line that fixed things:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 15):

In your Storyboard, select the problematic controller, look at the Attributes tab and try to edit these settings:

- Under Top Bars
- Under Opaque Bars

I've solved a similar problem by **unflagging** these settings.

Comment: I added a link to my project.. check it out

Comment: Nice solution. The only problem I found with this is that the navbar color for the view controller will be different (due to no more transparent overlay), so if you have multiple view controllers you may want to change them all to keep consistency

Comment: And Storyboards strike again!

Answer (score 8):

I found what is causing this issue. Seems that the animation gets messed up when you set navigationBar.translucent to NO. If you make your navigationBar translucent, everything should work fine, but this is definitely not an ideal solution. I'm going to try and find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableView *_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                           64,
                                                           self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                           self.view.frame.size.height)
                                          style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:_tableView];

// adding uisearch bar
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

_tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;



//
UISearchDisplayController* searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
```

and I just embade my controller with UINavigationcontroller and its working quite well..[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel animation by subclassing UISearchDisplayController and adding this:

```
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     if(self.active == visible) return;
     [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
     [super setActive:visible animated:animated];
     [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
     if (visible) {
          [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
     } else {
          [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[codyko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864693/codyko) gave me an idea.  It was the because the navigation bar was no translucent.  So I set it to translucent on this view controller and rest when I left with the following code:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Now that left the navigation bar on this controller slightly faded, so I added a `UIView` the same color as my navbar just behind it to make it look opaque. I know it isn't perfect but it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating the searchBar programmatically instead of in the StoryBoard ? 
I'm currently using searchBar, added in storyboard and it's work fine ( I have to change the contentOffset )

Comment: What do you mean for changing the content offset? can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: Yep, there is it : 
`-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -60)];
}`

Answer (score -2):

I have applied your code,, It works fine for me,, Just hide you navigation bar and start the search bar from y = 20, instead of y = 0;

Comment: Could you send a link to your test please so that I can compare please

Comment: There is no navigation bar in your test

Comment: im using the navigation bar in the App I dont think its the way to go