# How to prevent UISearchBar from shifting up

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I put UISearchBar under UIView as the picture below. The problem is - after finish search or click cancel, UISearchBar will shift to the top, then I get error message:

```
2014-05-22 15:45:18.663 MyAPP[14402:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
2014-05-22 15:45:18.667 MyAPP[14402:60b] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.06 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.
2014-05-22 15:45:23.697 MyAPP[14402:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Question:

1) Is it possible to fix position of UISearchBar? and How to do that?

2) How to fix the error?

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: I am not sure but please ensure that checkmark of Use Autolayout should be none.

Comment: Also you can get help from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467945/uisearchbar-animation-issue